# Assembly x86 - timing events

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

I am running Assembly x86 code on the DosBox emulator (On Windows7), compiled using TASM.
So far in my code I have only used nested loops for delays in code, but now that I am running my code on different cycle rates I see this is not the best solution. Searching the web for code examples or interrupts of how to created a timer and use it instead of nested loops was of no use, and I only saw some vague example on wikipedia about something called PIT which I did not understand.

Can someone please provide an idea with a valid code example of how this could be done? Thank you!

**EDIT**

I tried using this code for a delay using the int 21h interrupt, but for some reason it turned out to be a lot slower than the 20 1/100 seconds intended.. Maybe this could be fixed?

```
redo:   mov ah, 2ch
        int 21h     ;MILIS IN DL            ;BUG HERE -> FIX TIMER
        cmp dl, 79
        jnc redo
        mov milis, dl
loop1:  mov ah, 2ch
        int 21h
        sub dl, milis
        cmp dl, 20
        jc loop1
```

Comment: Timing operations are either strongly associated with a particular operating system or a specific hardware platform.  Please add the appropriate tags.  I'll remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Since this is riding on top of the DOSBOS simulator, are you sure this matters?

Comment: You have the choice of interfacing to the (emulated) x86, BIOS, or MSDOS.  Now that there is code posted, it is clear you are using the latter.

Comment: @wallyk ok, but do you see something wrong with that code?

Comment: I am confused by the magic constants `79` and `20`:  what do they mean?  Also note that the 0.01 seconds count returned in DL usually does not increment by one.  See [this](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2703.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In the world of DOS there are many ways to achieve a delay. The bios maintains a time counter that increments 18.2 times per second or every 55ms so you could interrogate that and loop until the appropriate ticks have passed based on how long you want to delay. You can read the 4 byte counter value from the BIOS data area at address 40:6C.

But a simpler approach would be to use interrupt 15h function 86h which is a bios implemented delay. I am not sure it works in DosBOX, but technically it should.

Here is a reference

http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1525.htm